# Get products in Magento 2 by option's SKU

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I wonder how to get products where the product options->SKU field is 'MyOptionSku' in Magento 2.

Something like

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Collection $optCollection */
$foundProducts = $optCollection->getAllProductsWhichOptionsSkuIs('MyOptionSku')
```

**UPDATE:**

Screenshot from Admin Backend

[image: product_options_screenshot]

**UPDATE**

It is not possible to do that. Reason: The author of the Magento Shop has created these option fields "Titel", "Preis" and "SKU". SKU is a free text field. As Philipp Sander said, options has no SKU.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get product by sku?

Comment: what do oyu mean by option sku? options do not have a SKU

Comment: @Rohan: no. I have custom product options (like 'pressure' and others). And I have to find all products which options' SKU matching 'MyOptionSku'. Lets say a product has the option 'pressure'. This option has an entry with text '7 bar' and SKU 'MyOptionSku', antother entry with text '8 bar' and SKU 'AnotherSku'.

Comment: options do not have SKUs. are you talking about configurable products? can you provide us a screenshot from the product in the adminhtml?